# Increment month number by 1 SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update a column value incrementing by 1, the column is month_number and it is defined as integer, when the month is 12, I need to update to 1 instead of 13

I first tried this approach:

```
update tab
set col_month = col_month + 1
```

But won't work for cases where col_month is 12

Comment: what type is col_month? and do you have a constraint when create the table?

Comment: the type is integer, I do have a constraint, col_month is FK that references a table where is defined my months, so col_month can only be in the interval [1,12]

Comment: If you have something like CHECK col_month >=1 AND CHECK col_month <=12 or something, perhaps in your create table?

Comment: I believe the answer below answers it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one method using a `case` statement:

```
update tab
set col_month = case when col_month = 12 then 1 else col_month + 1 end
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that the easiest way is to use modulo operator `%`.

```
UPDATE
    tab
SET
    col_month = (col_month % 12) + 1
```

Modulo operator gives you the range 0 - 11 (12 is changed to 0) and you just need to add 1.

Comment: this is neat indeed

Answer (score 1):

I think you should still work with dates for dates. Eg:

```
select extract( month from now() + '5 month'::interval)::int;
```

Gives you 1, not 13. and it is `int` as you want. and you dont invent a wheel with `case` or all cases.